# Save if a field should be used - SQL

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, phpmyadmin

I am creating a new application, it's like a form builder. The administrator can select with HTML checkboxes if a field should be appear in a form. Now I have multiple field and tables in my database for saving the data but I have no clue how I could tell for each field if it should be used or not.

**For example.**

```
tbl_users
- firstname
- lastname
- street
- country
- city

tbl_data1
- datafield1
- datafield2
- datafield3

tbl_data2
- checkbox1
- checkbox2
- checkbox3
```

I was thinking about adding somewhere a '1' or '0' for if the field should be used/rendered or not. 
What is the best way to save this? Using an 'between table'?

**Like:**

```
admin_generated_field
- id             1
- user_id        32
- checkbox       0
- checkbox1      1
- checkbox2      0
- textfield1     1
```

I hope my question is a bit clear, and I hope someone can help me out a bit or sugget me some tips thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add a table with one row for each input in your form, like below

```
active_elements
-id
-column_name
-visible
```

Then query the table for visible elements.  If you are using PDO it would look like

```
<?php
$user = 'admin';
$pass = '';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$active = $dbh->query('SELECT column_name from active_elements WHERE visible=1')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
?>
```

Finally in your form view you search the $active array before displaying an input

```
if(in_array('q1', $active)){
    print "<label for='form[q1]'>Q1:</label><input name='form[q1] type='text' />";
}
```

One more thought, ask yourself: is this a presentation problem, an access control problem, or both? Minimally it seems like you want to run this test at the view layer, but maybe you want to do it at the model layer as well (if you aren't using the MVC pattern, that just means you would integrate the test into code that is processing the form submissions).